# Twitter API return "Unknown error" in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, twitter

I use Laravel 5 + thujohn Twitter API. On localhost. Accounts are added successfully. It means that all settings are correct. In case of any interaction with Twitter API (POST, GET, etc.) always returns: "[0] Unknown error". And no more info. Twitter::logs() returns empty array, always.

That I tried to do:

- to update all keys and application controls
- to delete application from all accounts in Twitter and to deliver it zany
- in every possible way to change url "Website" and "Callback URL", for example "http://127.0.0.1:8000", "http://127.0.0.1:8080", and others
- to delete application and to create new

I can't show a code, it is forbidden

Answer (score 0):

At the next day it working. I do not know the reason. I just `composer update` the project, but I'm not sure what helped it.